# Как сделать автоматическую вставку контента(текст, картинки) в юнити по шаблону?

Tags: c#, прокрутка, автоматизация, unity3d-ui

Всем привет! Я новичок в юнити, делаю информационный киоск для музея с огромным количеством контента, использую везде ScrollRect и туда запихиваю весь контент. Дело это довольно долгое, поэтому хочу узнать у профи: можно ли автоматизировать вставку контента? Допустим чтобы картинки с названием "раздел1.1.*номер картинки*" и текст на фрейме, который идет рядом с картинкой, из соответствующей папки сами подгружались в юнити с ограничением по размеру, но с сохранением родных пропорций и автоматически подключался GridLayot для растягивания поля контента в зависимости от его количества. Пробовала путем описания задачи получить скрипт от ИИ, но ничего не работает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему, может есть какие-то плагины специальные для этого, потому что с программированием я хоть и знакома, но не эксперт

Comment: Если вам реальное 3Д не надо, проще было бы использовать десктопные UI движки, например WPF или MAUI. Пилить красивые интерфейсы на Unity - весьма трудоёмкая задача. А ещё оно ресурсов будет в разы больше кушать: зачем вам киоск, перерисовывающий свои нажимаемые раз в 100 лет кнопочки с частотой 120 FPS? А так берите `Directory.GetFiles(path)` и вперёд.

Comment: Ресурсы можно подгружать через вызов Resources.Load, это старый подход. Есть ещё новый - используя Addressables.